# Google Sheets - Volatile function RANDBETWEEN recalculating on cell activation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two RANDBETWEEN functions that are recalculating when I simply navigate to or from (i.e. "activate") a cell with content.  As I understand it - and as it has been functioning since I created my sheet years ago - the RANDBETWEEN function recalculates on an *edit* to any cell.  But I am not editing any cells - I'm simply activating cells.  The function does not recalculate if I move between empty cells.

Furthermore, if I load the sheet and try to Ctrl-Z undo (undoing essentially nothing), the RANDBETWEEN function will recalculate.

The Recalculation setting for my spreadsheet is "On change" and I've never changed it.  I did toggle it once the issue started but it did not fix the issue.

I have a lot of macros/scripts within this sheet but none of them are simple triggers like onEdit(e). I tried commenting out all of my code files and deleting my triggers but the issue persists.  I tried RANDBETWEEN and other volatile functions on a different Spreadsheet and those function as expected, so it's only this specific Spreadsheet I'm struggling with.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue. Can you provide a sample of your working sheet that has the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - I was calling a custom function in a cell in my spreadsheet which I had apparently deleted from my Script editor.  When I deleted the function in the cell, the recalculation functionality returned to normal.